# Does it make sense to install an SSD into a 3rd generation MacBook?

Tags: macbook, upgrade, ssd

I've heard that, to really benefit from a solid-state drive, one needs a motherboard fast enough. Do you think it's worth to install an SSD into this laptop?

```
Model Name: MacBook
Model Identifier: MacBook3,1
Processor Name: Intel Core 2 Duo
Processor Speed: 2.2 GHz
Number Of Processors: 1
Total Number Of Cores: 2
L2 Cache: 4 MB
Memory: 4 GB
Bus Speed: 800 MHz
Boot ROM Version: MB31.008E.B02
```

I mean, will I *really* feel a day—night difference from a HDD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your definition of ***worth it***. An SSD in this system will make it significantly faster, save battery life, etc. Will it be as fast as the same SSD in a newer system? Probably not quite, but I think you'll be very happy with the results anyway. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you can use out it's speed. An SSD always gives a new life to a laptop, so if you think you'll be fine with that machine for a while, then buy an SSD instead of getting a new MBP/MB. (Seriously its like resurrecting a machine. :) Well.. you can get one and later put it in your new laptop. Which one? I don't know. Intel X25 E maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that an SSD always makes a huge difference. I installed an extremely fast OCZ Vertex2 in a 1st gen MacBook and it really didn't help much, largely because it was constrained by the SATA 1 interface, and thus wasn't much faster than the 7200rpm HDD I had before. With SATA 2 it's a different story - I moved the drive to a more recent Mac Mini and it flies - and I'd expect you'd see similar gains with a later MacBook.